# How to do an Https Post from a Web application using X509 and pkcs#7 certificate in Java

Tags: java, ssl

I have spent hours figuring out the solution to this problem. Have come across many different blogs and questions on stackoverflow. But nothing seems to work. I have the following files provided from client side: 
1.) Der Encoded Binary X.509.cer 
2.) Base 64 encoded X.509.cer 
3.) PKCS#7 Certificates.p7b

I managed to export PKCS#12.pfx certificate in windows 8. But I cannot register it in JDK1.7. 
I am getting the error Null Pointer Exception - not X.509 certificate I am also using simple HttpsUrlConnection to connect to the website I am installing certificates for. 
I am pretty much a beginner in this field of Java. 
Please help me.

Comment: Are you doing a post to a web application, or a post from a web application?  If the latter, to what are you posting?

Comment: I am doing post to a web application.

Comment: If the certificate is a server certificate that you have to tell your client program to accept, you'll need to use Java keytool to put the certificate into the Java trust store.  If you're not sure what this means, please provide (1) a snippet of the code that connects to the web site, and (2) the complete stack trace for the NullPointerException, and I'll try to help further.